Hvac crawlspace vent preventing AC from reaching the front bedroom
We live on one floor in a new development and it has two bedrooms. The front bedroom is not getting much AC because the duct running in the crawlspace has a vent, in line. When I have the AC on I can feel the air coming through that vent quite strong. If I close the shutters on the vent down there, its better in the bedroom. But I need to know to what extent that will affect the system and anything else like humidity down there.
We have a cement floor and the walls are sealed and insulated in the crawlspace.
Thanks

Shutters/dampers are usually provide to tune a system.  Might take some time of testing to get the right settings for both rooms. Somewhere between total open/close.

If the dampers don't do the job, there are vent faces that incorporate fans to help draw air in the desired direction.
